# Difference between TypeScript optional type and type | undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I am struggling to understand the difference between having a field defined as `string | undefined` and `string?`

Our current code uses type definitions like this one:

```
class Foo {
  public bar: string | undefined;
}
```

When running this code through TSLint it will take notice and complain about it:

> Consider using '?' syntax to declare this property instead of 'undefined' in its type.

Now the question is will using the `?` syntax work exactly the same or are there subtle differences that I am missing?

```
class Foo {
  public bar?: string;
}
```

So how we are using the `string | undefined` type right now is in checks like this one:

`if (foo.bar) {..}` Will this change?

It seems the typescript documentation goes into depth about optional types but not really into how this behaves in a class context.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`bar?: string` is an optional property, whereas `bar: string | undefined` is a required one:

```
interface Foo { 
    bar?: string
}

interface Foo2 {
    bar: string | undefined
}

const foo: Foo = {} // OK
const foo2: Foo2 = {} // error, bar is required
const foo2: Foo2 = {bar: undefined} // OK
```

Regarding this case:

```
if (foo.bar) {..}
```

Both approaches are OK (including that Intellisense works in either way).

Comment: After reading your answer I am still confused with my question So can you take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053275/how-do-i-type-my-options-parameter-in-order-to-call-fs-readfilesync ?

Answer (score 9):

As of Typescript 4.4, you can use the `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` option to make optional properties even more different from `type | undefined`.

By default, Typescript actually treats this...

```js
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age?: number;
}
```

...the same as this...

```js
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age?: number | undefined;
}
```

In other words, the `?` actually *adds* undefined to the type definition, in addition to allowing you to ignore that property. Any of these assignments is acceptable:

```js
const tom: Person = {name: "tom", age: 53};
// This is allowed because of `?`, which adds `undefined` to the type
const john: Person = {name: "john", age: undefined};
// This is allowed because of `?`
const mary: Person = {name: "mary"};
```

But when using `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`, the second one is not allowed by an optional type:

```js
const tom: Person = {name: "tom", age: 53};
// This is NOT allowed with just `?`. You have to explicitly add `undefined` to the type
const john: Person = {name: "john", age: undefined};
// This is allowed because of `?`
const mary: Person = {name: "mary"};
```

See the [typescript 4.4 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) for more information.

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the accepted.

Answer (score 5):

`bar: string | undefined`: the property has to be declared and it can be either a string or `undefined`.

`bar?: string`: the property can be not declared; if it's declared see before.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as above ones, with code example

```js
// optional property, may be skipped
type Foo = {
    bar?: string; // i.e. string | undefined, optional
};

const a: Foo = {
    bar: undefined, // ok
};

const a2: Foo = { } // also ok

const a3: Foo = {
    bar: null, // ERROR!! Must be string OR undefined
};

const a4: Foo = {
    bar: 'sup', // ok, obviously
};

// --------------------

// property is NOT optional, must be declared
type Foo2 = {
    bar: string | undefined; // REQUIRED
}

const b: Foo2 = { } // ERROR!!

const b2: Foo2 = {
    bar: undefined, // ok
};

const b3: Foo2 = {
    bar: null, // ERROR!! Must be string OR undefined
};

const b4: Foo2 = {
    bar: 'sup', // ok, obviously
};
```

Also there is this difference dealing with these types at runtime:

```js
const a1 = { b: undefined }
Object.keys(a1).forEach(k => console.log(k))
// CONSOLE: b

const a2 = {}
Object.keys(a2).forEach(k => console.log(k))
// CONSOLE:
```