# What's the difference between "?" and "| undefined"?

Tags: typescript, option-type, optional-parameters

I'm wondering, is there a difference (actual or best practices wise) between

```
interface Fruit {
  cost?: number;
}
```

and

```
interface Fruit {
  cost: number | undefined;
}
```

If there is an actual difference in terms of behaviour, what is it?

If there isn't, why would one prefer `| undefined` or `?:` (or vice versa)?

Sort of confused because I've seen both, and not sure if there's actually an actual reason for preferring one over the other, or if it's something that just boils down to preference.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between TypeScript optional type and type | undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371363/difference-between-typescript-optional-type-and-type-undefined)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One difference is that `cost: number | undefined;` *requires* the property to exist, and have a value whose type is `number` or `undefined`. In contrast, `cost?: number` permits the property to not exist at all.

This fails to compile:

```
interface Fruit {
    cost: number | undefined;
}
const x: Fruit = {};
```

For it to work, you'd have to do:

```
interface Fruit {
    cost: number | undefined;
}
const x: Fruit = { cost: undefined };
```

But this succeeds:

```
interface Fruit {
    cost?: number;
}
const x: Fruit = {};
```

Explicitly typing `undefined` can be tedious when an alternative is available, so you'll probably prefer the `cost?: number` option.

Comment: Wow, I honestly didn't know - my instinct has always been to prefer `?:` over `| undefined`, but I could never put it in words - never thought to actually experiment. That makes perfect sense - thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: I just experimented a bit and this applies to function arguments as well - what an interesting feature. Will definitely keep this in mind. Thanks again!