# Accessed property has different narrowed type when assigned to constant

Tags: typescript, types

I have a type and object defined like this:

```ts
type A = {
  b?: string | undefined
}

const a: A = {
  b: "test"
}
```

I wanted to check that `b` exists and is not undefined but after the check `b`'s type is still possibly `undefined`:

```ts
if (a.b) {
  // expected type: b: string
  // actual type: b?: string
  a.b
}
```

I would have expected the type to be narrowed to `string` (in my a actual code the expected code is not a primitive, so not even the case of `b` being the empty string could interfere).

I found some explanations about the difference between optional properties and properties where the type is a union with `undefined`: ["Difference between TypeScript optional type and type | undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53371363/5622577). But my expectation still would have been that typescript can infer at this place that `b` exists and is not undefined.

I found a workaround by assigning the property to a new constant. This leads to my actual question: Why is the type correctly narrowed when `b` is assigned to a new constant?

```ts
if (a.b) {
  // expected type: c: string
  // actual type: c: string
  const c = a.b
}
```

Comment: Although the type is shown that way, [it doesn't appear to get in the way of using `a.b`](https://tsplay.dev/WPgVzm) (for instance, there's no error on `a.b.length`). If you're running into an actual error using it, please update the question with an example of that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It seems I did not reproduce my problem correctly. I'll have to open a more specific question for that but I'll edit this question so it is clear I'm interested in the difference of the inferred types.

Comment: Again, though, it makes no difference. Although I'll grant you that the type hint shown for `a.b` includes optionality, the type is **treated** as straight-up `string`, as shown above (and [here](https://tsplay.dev/NVYElw)). So what, in real code terms, is the issue?

Comment: In real code terms there is no problem but I would still like to know the reason for this discrepancy. My interest in this is now mostly academic. I would be satisfied by an answer that tells me this is a bug and I should open an issue with the typescript devs or an answer that explains that this is expected and why. It isn't obvious to me which of these possibilities are correct and for anyone else, who observes this behavior it might not either.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for clarifying! :-) I have to say it looks at least bug-adjacent to me. ;-)